# Attempting to install SUPEE 6285 CE 1.8.1.0

Tags: ce-1.8.1.0, patches

Trying to install the above and I am running into this error:

> 1 out of 1 hunk ignored -- saving rejects to file
>   app/design/frontend/default/modern/template/checkout/cart.phtml.rej
>   The next patch would create the file downloader/Maged/.htaccess, which
>   already exists!  Assume -R? [n] Apply anyway? [n] Skipping patch. 1
>   out of 1 hunk ignored patching file downloader/Maged/Controller.php
>   patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Session.php The next patch would
>   create the file downloader/lib/.htaccess, which already exists! 
>   Assume -R? [n] Apply anyway? [n] Skipping patch. 1 out of 1 hunk
>   ignored patching file downloader/template/connect/packages.phtml
>   patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml Hunk
>   1 FAILED at 33. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej patching file
>   downloader/template/login.phtml patching file
>   downloader/template/settings.phtml patching file errors/processor.php
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 460. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to
>   file errors/processor.php.rej

How do I fix this to patch correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if the patch has already been applied by using this online scantool.

[Magereport](https://www.magereport.com/)

there is also this site that has pre-patched files for people who are having issues manually patching their system.

[Ultimate Magento Patch Guide](https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-magento-security-patches/)